# Generate a random number without a given digit

Tags: c, random, numbers

I want to generate a random number without a specific single digit like random numbers without `5` are `240`,`237`,`112`, `198` etc. I want to do this in C programming.

Comment: You have expressed a desire but neglected to ask a question. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The task itself seems straightforward. Put the remaining digits in an array of length 9, and sample from that array.

Comment: just call _rand_ in a loop while the result contains the unexpected digit

Comment: You want to do this in C programming... So get to it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up an array of digits without the missing digit: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9].
2. Pick digits from the array to assemble the number.